# Why is the order of elements in my list mixed up when I pass them through a generator?

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to convert elements in a nested list to strings before joining them with " | " using the join operator. However, the order of the last 2 elements in my list keeps getting reversed when I get the output from the generator

I've tried running the program multiple times but it always comes out reversed.

```
numbers = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for i in numbers:
     print(i)
     num = {str(x) for x in i}
     print(num)
```

Expected Output is [1,2,3].
Actual output is [1,3,2] consistently.

Any help with this would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a generator, it's a set comprehension. The result is a set, and sets are unordered.

Use a list comprehension:

```
num = [str(x) for x in i]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification!